# Rational Matrix Powers with certain rowsum vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projection

Given a set of $n$ vectors in a $n$-dimensional vector space $\{u_1, u_2,...,u_n\}$ I am interested in a method to get a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ whose first $n$ powers have each of those vectors as rowsum which means that for $1\leq k\leq n$ the matrix $A$ verifies

$$A^k \begin{align}
     \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           1 \\
           \vdots \\
           1 \\
           1
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align} = u_k.$$

Answer (score 0):

This isn't always guaranteed.  You need additional constraints on what your vectors can be.

**Counterexample**
Consider the vectors
$$
u_1 \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{c}
1\\1\\
\end{array} \right ] \hspace{3pc} u_2 \;\; =\;\; \left [\begin{array}{c}
-1 \\ 1 \\
\end{array} \right ].
$$

Then the we want a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ that satisfies $Au_1 = u_1$ and $A^2u_1 = u_2$.  By the first constraint we want that
$$
\left [\begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\ c & d \\
\end{array} \right ]\left [ \begin{array}{c}
1\\1\\
\end{array} \right ] \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{c}
a+b \\ c+d \\
\end{array} \right ] \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{c}
1\\1\\
\end{array} \right ].
$$

When we try to find $A^2$ to obtain our second vector we find that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left [\begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\ c & d \\
\end{array} \right ]\left [\begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\ c & d \\
\end{array} \right ]\left [ \begin{array}{c}
1\\1\\
\end{array} \right ] & = & \left [\begin{array}{cc}
a^2 + bc & b(a+d) \\
c(a+d) & d^2 + bc \\
\end{array} \right ]\left [ \begin{array}{c}
1\\1\\
\end{array} \right ] \\
& = & \left [ \begin{array}{c}
a^2 + b(a+c+d) \\
d^2 + c(a+b+d) \\
\end{array} \right ] \\
& = & \left [ \begin{array}{c}
a^2 + ab + b \\
d^2 + cd+c \\
\end{array} \right ] \\
& = &  \left [ \begin{array}{c}
a+b \\
c+d \\
\end{array} \right ]\;\; =\;\;\left [ \begin{array}{c}
1\\1\\
\end{array} \right ].
\end{eqnarray*}

Therefore no matrix $A$ exists where $Au_1 = u_1$ and $A^2u_1 = u_2$.

Comment: Thanks @Mnifldz for editions improvements and for the comment on the choosen vectors set $\{u_1,...,u_n\}$. So we can add: "...whenever $A$ exists."

Comment: @24th_moonshine I think you’re really underestimating the “when $A$ exists” part here.  You’re asking for a highly specific procedure to occur here and it’s not going to work for most choices of vectors $u_1,\ldots,u_k$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u_0=[1,\cdots,1]^T$. Your required condition implies that $u_n$ is a linear combination of $u_0,\cdots,u_{n-1}$.

A better question is :

$\textbf{Proposition}$. Let $u_1,\cdots,u_{n-1},u_n$ be s.t. $u_0,u_1,\cdots,u_{n-1}$ is a basis of $K^n$.

Then, show that there is a unique matrix $A$ s.t. $A^ku_0=u_k,1\leq k\leq n$.

$\textbf{Proof}$. Note that $Au_0=u_1,Au_1=u_2,\cdots,Au_{n-1}=u_n$ and we may write $u_n=\sum_{0\leq i\leq n-1}a_iu_i$.

Let $P$ be the matrix of change of basis $(e_i)_i\rightarrow (u_j)_{0\leq j\leq n-1}$. Then $P^{-1}AP$ is THE companion matrix $C$ s.t. its $n^{th}$ column is $[a_0,\cdots,a_{n-1}]^T$. $\square$

EDIT.  Answer to the OP

$A=PCP^{-1}$ where $c_{i,j}=0$ except $c_{i+1,i}=1$ and $c_{i,n}=a_{i-1}$.

Comment: Hi @loup_blanc as far as I understand this proposition directly ensures that under these assumptions (s.t. and basis on corresponding vector sets) matrix $A$ exists and is unique. But I do not have a clear idea on how to get matrix $A$. Perhaps inverting basis change on $P^{−1}AP$ matrix, but not clear if all components from $P^{−1}AP$ are known. Thanks in advance!